# Flex 3: ButtonBar buttons with underline text

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, buttonbar

I'm using Flex 3 to build a button bar with several options. Is is possible to underline the labels of my buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the textDecoration property of your button.

```
<s:Button width="15%" height="32%" label="myButton" click="myButton_clickHandler(event)" textDecoration="underline"/>
```

Works for the buttonbar, as well.

```
<s:ButtonBar textDecoration="underline">

</s:ButtonBar>
```